# TinyMCE Validation in MVC and Umbraco using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, umbraco8

I cant get TinyMCE to validate when using the below code when using MVC application or Umbraco

```
<form name="evaluationForm" val-form-manager class="show-validation">
.... **Code removed**
 <tr>
                                <ng-form>
                                    <umb-property-editor model="rteDescription" required="{{vm.Description}}" ng-required="true"></umb-property-editor>
                                </ng-form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
.....


                <umb-button action="vm.save()"
                            label="Save"
                            type="button"
                            disabled="evaluationForm.$invalid"
                            button-style="action">
                </umb-button>
```

In my AngularJS controller i have

```
$scope.rteDescription = {
            view: "rte",
            config: {
                editor: {
                    toolbar: ["ace", "undo", "redo", "bold", "italic", "alignleft", "aligncenter", "alignright", "bullist", "numlist", "link", "umbmediapicker", "fullscreen"],
                    style_formats: [{ title: "Heading 1", inline: "h1" }],
                    plugins: ["fullscreen"],
                    stylesheets: [],
                    dimensions: { height: 300 }
                }
            }
        };
```

When i use code such as

```
 <td><input id="someName" ng-required="true" ng-model="vm.Name" required="{{vm.Name}}" /></td>
```

the button is disabled until i enter some text into the name textbox (so validation kicks in).

If i enter `ng-model=vm.Description` then the button remains disabled even though i have text in all relevant controls, considering this is the TinyMCE control that only has this issue, how can i get this to work so the user must enter some data in the TinyMCE control before data is saved to a database?

Edit 1

Immediately under the `$scope.rteDescription` code block (`after};`) I added

```
            tinymce.init({
                setup: function (editor) {
                    editor.on('change', function () {
                        console.log('Hello I have run!!');
                        tinymce.triggerSave();
                    });
                }
            });
```

but the console log never displays any feedback.

I have made changes to the control with text and deleted the text, clicked away from the editor etc but non of this executed the init event.

Answer (score 0):

When TinyMCE is injected into the page the original form element (e.g. `<textarea>`) is no longer visible.  If you use your browser tools you will see that TinyMCE injects a series of `<div>`s and an `<iframe>` effectively hiding your `<textarea>`.

Because of this, if you ask a validation tool to look at the value in the `<textarea>` it likely still has its initial value from when you first loaded TinyMCE.

In order to have your validation tool validate the underlying `<textarea>` you first have to update the `<textarea>` with the current contents of TinyMCE.  To do this you need to use TinyMCE's `triggerSave()` API.  This will force TinyMCE to immediately update the underlying `<textarea>` with the current value in the editor. At that point your validation tooling will know what content exists in the editor.

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    ...
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. I added the above code but it didnt do anything. If i use rteDescription.init - i get compile time error using tinyMCE.init doesnt but i dont see it being triggered anywhere? I changed selector to rte (name of my view) but that didnt do anything either. Am i missing something simple here?

Comment: The selector was just an example - you should be able to use the `init()` you already have in place and just add the setup configuration option.  To make sure its working at all perhaps add a console.log?

Comment: Im not sure if im missing a step but i have amended my original post to include the init method which doesnt seem to kick in. Please note, i dont have any init already in place and just added the above code to the existing controller. No errors listed in the console either??

Comment: The fact you have a config{} object in your code suggests that your CMS is likely handling the init() in some custom way - you will have to figure out how it is doing that and how you can add the setup configuration option to the init() that it is creating.   That is more of an Umbraco question for someone with Umbraco expertise.